# Canonical linear mapping is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space with finite dimension. Proof that mapping:
$V^* \otimes V \rightarrow {\rm End}_K(V), \ h\otimes a\mapsto (x\mapsto h(x)a)$ is bijective. So we have one mapping, which is just product of $2$ vectors. We get a new vector $x$ and then another simple mapping. Tensor product is bijective and every endomorphism also. So it has to be bijective. Can I use this argument or do I have to show it formally?

Comment: I can sort of make sense of what you're saying, but I have no idea what you mean by *"Tensor product is bijective and every endomorphism also"*.

Comment: Because we're dealing with a finite dimensional vector space, it suffices to show that the dimensions of the two spaces are the same and that the map is either injective or surjective.

Comment: Tensor product is mapping, but now I see that is not always bijectiv. Endomorphism in general is not bijectiv. I was thinking too fast

Comment: The tensor product $h \otimes a$ is not a mapping in its own right; at least, it isn't one under the usual consideration

Comment: I cannot consider it as mapping from 2 vectors of spaces with dimension n and m to vector in space with dimension nm ?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, $\otimes$ is itself a mapping from $V^*$ and $V$ to $V^* \otimes V$, sure.  This is not a linear map, though.  The mapping that we're trying to show is bijective is a linear transformation.

Comment: Ok. I'm learning in foreign language and I'm never sure about anything.

Comment: I appreciate that it must make things that much more confusing to have to translate; I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: What is your definition of the tensor product?   Is it something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Definition), or something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property)?

Comment: Second one. Thank's a lot :)

Comment: I wrote a proof that directly uses the second definition over [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1307770/81360).  This proof also works if the space is not finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it, please check it for mistakes. For starters, we have that: $$\dim(V^\ast \otimes V) = \dim({\rm End}_K(V)) = n^2.$$

Let $\Phi: V^\ast \otimes V \to {\rm End}_K(V)$ be the linear map characterized by $\Phi(h \otimes a)(x) = h(x)a$, for all $h\in V^*$ and $a\in V$ (i.e., obtained by applying the universal property of $V^*\otimes V$ to the bilinear map $V^*\times V \ni (h,a)\mapsto (x\mapsto h(x)a)\in {\rm End}_K(V)$).

We will show that $\Phi$ is surjective (and therefore an isomorphism, since the dimension of $V$ is finite). Let $T\in {\rm End}_K(V)$, and $(a_1,\ldots, a_k)$ be a basis for the range of $V$. Complete it to a basis $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ of $V$, and let $(h_1,\ldots, h_n)$ be the corresponding dual basis in $V^*$. Then we have that $$\Phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^k (T^*h_i)\otimes a_i\right) = T$$by design. To wit, we have that $$\Phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^k (T^*h_i)\otimes a_i\right)(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \Phi((T^*h_i)\otimes a_i)(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k h_i(T(x))a_i = T(x).$$

Comment: This proof works.  I deleted a redundant statement; feel free to put that back.

Comment: No problem, thanks!

Comment: Better to avoid the use of dimension equality, because there is a more general result which says that $\Phi : V^{\ast} \otimes W \to \operatorname{Hom}_K\left(V, W\right)$ (defined in the same way as your $\Phi$) is an isomorphism for any finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and arbitrary vector space $W$.

Comment: @Ivo I'm returning to this question in response to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4557525/81360), I think your proof of injectivity might have the same flaw as the proof in the question: you show that the decomposable elements (simple tensors) in the kernel must be zero, but this alone is not enough to conclude that the kernel is trivial.

Comment: @Ben You're absolutely right, this proof is not correct. It is easier to show that $\Phi$ is surjective instead by picking a basis for the image of the chosen endomorphism and building up a tensor from it. I think 2015 was exactly the year I started reading about these things on my own, so it's not surprising my toddler argument fails. I'll fix it when I get home (typing from mobile now). Thank you!

Comment: @Ivo For what it's worth, I obviously missed the issue with your proof at the time. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

An alternate proof: we can prove that this map is surjective as follows.

Take an arbitrary $A \in {\rm End}_K(V)$.  With respect to some basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $V$, we can write
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots \\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}}
$$
We then note that 
$$
A = \Phi \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} e_i^* \otimes e_j \right)
$$
Combining this with injectivity (see the other answer), we may deduce that the mapping is bijective, so that these spaces have the same dimension.

Comment: under the double sum, shouldn't we also use the dual basis, e.g., $e^{i}\otimes e_{j}$?

Comment: @rych yes, slight oversight there.