# isomorphism of vector spaces $U \otimes V^*$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products

I would like to show that there existis an isomorphism of vector spaces $ \phi: U \otimes V^* \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,U) $ with $\phi(u \otimes f)(v)=f(v)u$ for all $u \in U, f \in V^*, v \in V$. $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional.

I considered the function $\Phi: U \times V^* \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$ with $\Phi(u,f)=f(v)u$. Easy computations show that $\Phi$ is bilinear. Hence, we can apply the universal property of tensor products which means that there exists $\phi$ linear such that $\Phi=\phi \circ \otimes$ and $\Phi(u,f)=\phi(u \otimes f)$. Hence, $\phi: U \otimes V^* \rightarrow  \operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$ with $\phi(u \otimes f)(v)=f(v)u$ does indeed exist and is linear.

Now we want to show that $\phi$ is bijective. By assumption, $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional. Wlog say that $\operatorname{dim}(V)=m, \operatorname{dim}(U)=n$. Furthermore,
$\operatorname{dim}(V)= \operatorname{dim}(V^*)$ because $V$ is finite dimensional. Now we can conclude that
$\operatorname{dim}(U \otimes V)=nm=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Hom}(V,U))$. Hence, it is now enough to show injectivity.

Assume that $\phi(u \otimes f)(v)=0$. This means that either $f(v)=0$ for all $v \in V$ or $u=0$. As $u \otimes 0$ and $0 \otimes f$ equal zero, we can conclude that $\operatorname{ker}(f)=0$. Therefore, $\phi$ is injective and we're done.

I'm not completely sure whether my approach is correct. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Not every element of $U\otimes V^*$ is decomposable.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why this would be a problem in my proof.

Comment: Because you only considered a decomposable element $u\otimes f$ in your attempted proof of injectivity.

Comment: Thanks, I  think I kind of understand what you mean but I have no idea how to solve this problem. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Pick bases for $V,U$ and use them to construct bases for the domain and the range of $\phi$. Show that $\phi$ maps one of the bases to the other.

Comment: @sunflower234 [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1307739/81360) is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there is gap. Although $\phi$ has the property
$\phi(u \otimes f)(v) = f(v)u$, you must be aware that not all elements of $U \otimes V^*$ have the form $u \otimes f$, but are sums of such elements.

Therefore it does not suffice to show that $\phi(u \otimes f)(v) = 0$ implies $u \otimes f = 0$. I suggest to work with bases of $U \otimes V^*$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$. Let $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ be a basis of $U$ and $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ be a basis of $V$. Let $v_1^*,\ldots,v_m^*$ be the dual basis of $V^*$. Then the $u_i \otimes v_j^*$ form a basis of $U \otimes V^*$. A basis for $\operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$ is given by the $nm$ linear maps $w_{ij} : V \to U$ given by $w_{ij}(v_k) = \delta_{jk}u_i$. In fact, if $g : V \to U$ is linear, then $g(v_k) = \sum_{i=1}^n g_{ik} u_i$ with unique $g_{ik} \in K$. But then
$$(\sum_{i,j} g_{ij}w_{ij})(v_k) = \sum_{i,j} g_{ij}w_{ij}(v_k) = \sum_{i,j} g_{ij} \delta_{jk}u_i  = \sum_i g_{ik}u_i = g(v_k)$$
which means $g = \sum_{i,j} g_{ij}w_{ij}$.

It is now easy to verify that $\phi(u_i \otimes v_j^*) = w_{ij}$.

This proves that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! This really clears it up!